# Ordering subfigures inside a figure environment

Tags: floats, subfloats

How can I order the subfigures such that subfigure a,b,c is ordered one above the other in the left side of the figure and only subfigure d is in the right side of the figure?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{boxed}
\restylefloat{figure}


\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[h]
 \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
 \caption{subfig 1}\label{syntaxUW}
 \end{subfigure}    

 \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
 \caption{subfig 2}\label{UWBeispiel}
 \end{subfigure}

 \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
 \caption{subfig 3}\label{syntaxUW}
 \end{subfigure}

 \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
 \caption{subfig 4}\label{syntaxUW}
 \end{subfigure}            

\caption{fig 1}
\label{UWAbb}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you have more possibilities. The simple one is to omit empty line between last and one before subfigure. In this case the subfigure `d` will be vertically aligned with subfigure `c`.

More elegant result you can achieve with use of tabular environment:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{boxed}
\restylefloat{figure}

\usepackage{array}% for m type of column

    \begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{m{0.5\hsize}m{0.5\hsize}}
 \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
 \caption{subfig 1}\label{syntaxUW}
 \end{subfigure}

 \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
 \caption{subfig 2}\label{UWBeispiel}
 \end{subfigure}

 \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
 \caption{subfig 3}\label{syntaxUW}
 \end{subfigure}
    &
 \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
 \caption{subfig 4}\label{syntaxUW}
 \end{subfigure}
    \end{tabular}

\caption{fig 1}
\label{UWAbb}
\end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

For centering subfigures inside table columns you can redefine column types as

```
{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.5\hsize} ...}
```